# Cheat sheet for caffe / pycaffe?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, caffe, pycaffe

Does anyone know whether there is a cheat sheet for all important pycaffe commands?
I was so far using caffe only via Matlab interface and terminal + bash scripts.

I wanted to shift towards using ipython and work through the ipython notebook examples. However I find it hard to get an overview of all the functions that are inside the caffe module for python. (I'm also quite new to python).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The [pycaffe tests](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/python/caffe/test) and [this file](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/_caffe.cpp) are the main gateway to the python coding interface.

First of all, you would like to choose whether to use Caffe with CPU or GPU. It is sufficient to call `caffe.set_mode_cpu()` or `caffe.set_mode_gpu()`, respectively.

### Net

The main class that the pycaffe interface exposes is the `Net`. It has two constructors:

```
net = caffe.Net('/path/prototxt/descriptor/file', caffe.TRAIN)
```

which simply create a `Net` (in this case using the *Data Layer* specified for training), or

```
net = caffe.Net('/path/prototxt/descriptor/file', '/path/caffemodel/weights/file', caffe.TEST)
```

which creates a `Net` and automatically loads the weights as saved in the provided *caffemodel* file - in this case using the *Data Layer* specified for testing.

A `Net` object has several attributes and methods. They can be found [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/pycaffe.py). I will cite just the ones I use more often.

You can access the network blobs by means of `Net.blobs`. E.g.

```
data = net.blobs['data'].data
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = my_image
fc7_activations = net.blobs['fc7'].data
```

You can access the parameters (weights) too, in a similar way. E.g.

```
nice_edge_detectors = net.params['conv1'].data
higher_level_filter = net.params['fc7'].data
```

Ok, now it's time to actually feed the net with some data. So, you will use `backward()` and `forward()` methods. So, if you want to classify a single image

```
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = my_image
net.forward() # equivalent to net.forward_all()
softmax_probabilities = net.blobs['prob'].data
```

The `backward()` method is equivalent, if one is interested in computing gradients.

You can save the net weights to subsequently reuse them. It's just a matter of

```
 net.save('/path/to/new/caffemodel/file')
```

### Solver

The other core component exposed by pycaffe is the `Solver`. There are several types of solver, but I'm going to use only `SGDSolver` for the sake of clarity. It is needed in order to train a caffe model.
You can instantiate the solver with

```
solver = caffe.SGDSolver('/path/to/solver/prototxt/file')
```

The `Solver` will encapsulate the network you are training and, if present, the network used for testing. Note that they are usually the same network, only with a different *Data Layer*. The networks are accessible with

```
 training_net = solver.net
 test_net = solver.test_nets[0] # more than one test net is supported
```

Then, you can perform a solver iteration, that is, a forward/backward pass with weight update, typing just

```
 solver.step(1)
```

or run the solver until the last iteration, with

```
 solver.solve()
```

### Other features

Note that pycaffe allows you to do more stuff, such as [specifying the network architecture through a Python class](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/test/test_net_spec.py) or [creating a new *Layer* type](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/test/test_python_layer.py).
These features are less often used, but they are pretty easy to understand by reading the test cases.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you. Just googled for the meaning of the three dots in `net.blobs['data'].data[...]`. Apparently it is a short form of addressing all elements in the matrix which would normally be written as `[:,:,:]`.

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept the answer if it's work for you.

Comment: Awesome post. Thank you. One small item: when I access net.params['conv'] (for example) I get that it is a BlobVec, not a Blob, so an access like nets.params['conv1'].data does not make sense. Instead, that vector needs to be indexed (e.g. net.params['conv1'][0].data) in order to get a Blob from which you can extract .data. Maybe someone else can comment on why this might not match the cheatsheet above (maybe newer version?), but it seemed worth sharing.

Comment: @FlavioFerrara: I want to do real-time augmentation such as rotation, shearing etc. So `net.blobs['data'].data[...] = my_altered_image`. After I do `net.forward()`, how do I update the weights of the model without saving it to disk using `net.save`?

Comment: When you want to update the weights of the model, you probably want a Solver. It handles the forward/backward pass and the weight update for you. Real-time data augmentation can be done by implementing a **custom DataLayer**, which is pretty easy to do in Python. See [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/test/test_python_layer.py)

Comment: is there a way to specify a solver configuration using python? or do you have to write it out in a text file manually?

Comment: There seems to be no way to specify a solver through a specific class. Yet, you can use a Temporary File inside Python, like [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/test/test_solver.py#L15-L21). IMO, it's not so clear through

Comment: Thanks for the post!

Comment: @FlavioFerrara you mentioned that "more than one test net is supported". Do you know the syntax to specify more than one test net in the solver prototxt file?

Comment: I believe you can simply specificy multiple `test_net` parameters.

Comment: After specifying data with `net.blobs['data'].data[...] = my_image`, shouldn't we forward using something like `net.forward(start='conv1')`? Otherwise the net would reload data as specified in prototxt descriptor file.

Comment: +1 for such a clear answer. Is there way to specify the network architecture for deploy.prototxt within python? More details about my question are here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986009/how-to-programmatically-generate-deploy-txt-for-caffe-in-python

Comment: Does somebody have prebuild binaries of caffe/pycaffe as it is unavailable. Please share I was not able to build it properly even after many attempts.

Answer (score 10):

Please note that the answer by Flavio Ferrara has a litte problem which may cause you waste a lot of time:

```
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = my_image
net.forward()
```

The code above is noneffective if your first layer is a Data type layer, because when `net.forward()` is called, it will begin from the first layer, and then your inserted data `my_image` will be covered. So it will show no error but give you totally irrelevant output. The correct way is to assign the start and end layer, for example:

`net.forward(start='conv1', end='fc')`

Here is a Github repository of Face Verification Experiment on LFW Dataset, using pycaffe and some matlab code. I guess it could help a lot, especially the `caffe_ftr.py` file.

https://github.com/AlfredXiangWu/face_verification_experiment

Besides, here are some short example code of using pycaffe for image classification：

http://codrspace.com/Jaleyhd/caffe-python-tutorial/
http://prog3.com/sbdm/blog/u011762313/article/details/48342495

Comment: On your note on setting image in data. Does it also cause trouble with solver.step(1)?