# How to load caffemodel weights for retraining using Pycaffe?

Tags: caffe

How to load caffemodel weights (alongside with a solver) to use subsequently for retraining using Python?

In other words, what would be the counterpart of the following command line in Pycaffe?

```
build/tools/caffe train \
-solver models/finetune_flickr_style/solver.prototxt \
-weights models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cheat sheet for caffe / pycaffe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379878/cheat-sheet-for-caffe-pycaffe)

Comment: No. Please note that the proposed duplicate question has no answer to my question.

Comment: it has in its last part

Comment: "Solver", "Other features"? In neither of the parts, it is explained how to load a caffemodel for retraining. If you see it, please make it into an answer,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loading caffemodel for finetuning with a particular solver can be obtained in Pycaffe by means of `get_solver()` and `net.copy_from()` functions:

```
solver=caffe.get_solver('prototxtfile.prototxt')
solver.net.copy_from('weights.caffemodel')
```