# How to train and test LeNet using caffe using python

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am new to caffe and Machine learning algorithms. Are there any tutorials to train and **TEST** LeNet on the MNIST data using caffe and python 2.7(preferably). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's caffe's ipython notebook example [Learning LeNet](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb).

The code is not limited to ipython notebook (although easier to navigate). You can copy them into the python interpreter and run them there.