# Train a network on python wrraper caffe?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I would like to train a caffe network with the python interface.
The main reason behind this is I use multi dimentional input of a few Tbs of data and I dont want to convert all this to LMDB and train it.

I have found a this [one answer on stack overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385427/how-to-train-a-caffe-model)

But his loads this complete data at once and has initialized weights.

I would like to load data to a numpy and then pass it to the caffe.

And save the weights of the caffemodel to a `.caffemodel` file once every 1000 iterations.

the `print_network()  get_accuracy() & load_data()` are very useful. And gives me a good inside.

Comment: have you considered using `type: "Python"` layer as your input layer? See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34996628/1714410) how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Beside using `PythonLayer` , one thing you can do is use `MemoryData` layer and feed in each batch of data at a time by using `solver.net.set_input_arrays(your_data)` after however many iteration is needed to go through one batch of data.

Remember, you can always restore the training state by using `.solverstate` file from your snapshots.